# Why does my compare not work?

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML with an `onchange` event I am trying to compare a drop down list to an array of specific elements. The drop down list uses type constants so, even though the user selects text, they are actually selecting a numeric value. If the specific element is selected my three radio buttons will be enabled. If the user changes their selection, or they do not select the specific objects in the array the default radio button is selected and all the radio buttons are disabled. `

```js
 function enableRadioButtons() {
 
 var RESULTED_IN_ACCIDENT_REQUIRED_CHARGE = [102508,233773,233774];

    for(var i = 0; i < RESULTED_IN_ACCIDENT_REQUIRED_CHARGE.length; i++) {
      if (document.getElementByTagName(select).value == RESULTED_IN_ACCIDENT_REQUIRED_CHARGE) {
       document.getElementByName("optradio").disabled = false;
      }
      else {
       document.getElementById("radio3").checked = true;
       document.getElementByName("optradio").disabled = true;
      }
    }
 }
```

#### Code for the onchange event

```html
<html:select styleClass="input" name="drivingRecordForm" property="conviction.chargeTid" onchange="enableRadioButtons(this)">
        <html:option value="0">Select one...</html:option>
          <optgroup label="Moving">
               <html:options collection="movingChargeOptions" property="value" labelProperty="label" />
          </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Non-Moving">
               <html:options collection="nonMovingChargeOptions" property="value" labelProperty="label" />
          </optgroup>
        </html:select>
```

#### Code for my radio buttons

```html
          
          <tr valign="bottom">
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2">Did the violation result in an accident?</td>
      <td colspan="2">
      <label for="radio1">
      <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="optradio" value="radioyes" disabled="disabled">Yes
      </label>
      <label for="radio2">
   <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="optradio" value="radiono" disabled="disabled">No
   </label>
   <label for="radio3">
   <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="optradio" value="radiounk" checked disabled="disabled">Unknown
   </label>
   </td>
   </tr>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should be seeing errors in the browser developer console.

Comment: This is easily solved with basic debugging. Have you done any?

Comment: Welcome! what exactly do you mean by not working? do you get any errors? what is the incorrect behaviour that you see?

Comment: Hello all and hello KLibby. Thank you for the quick response and thank you for the nice greeting.The problem is when I run the app my radio button stay disabled. What should happen is whenever the specific moving violation is selected the radio buttons should enable so the user can select one of them. That part is not working, but everything else is great. I know it has something to do with my function, my array or the way I am calling the function. Also, I ran the debugger and there are no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to check a value against an array of values, so your if statement should use `.indexOf()`

`RESULTED_IN_ACCIDENT_REQUIRED_CHARGE.indexOf(document.getElementByTagName(select).value) >= 0`

If the index is greater than or equal to zero, that means the value is in the array.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This didn't fix my issue, but it did help fix my array. I appreciate all that you did.